# navigationBar and it's titleView rightBarButtonItem became smaller with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

At normal state UI is like follow

[image]

when tableview slide up, i want the navigationBar became small with animation.
Code like follow

```
CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
shake.duration = DURATION_TIME;

shake.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0 ,1.0)];
shake.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.5, 1.0)];

shake.removedOnCompletion = NO;
shake.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
```

after the animation UI like follow

[image]

I don't want the navigationBar's y position change. And the titleView and rightbarItem became flat, How to avoid them becomes flat?

Comment: Can you tell me what do you want? Do you want the navigationBar's height is half with its y position unchanged?

Comment: @KudoCC yes, you said is what i want, and i also hope the titleview not change flat only scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. It works before ios7

```
UIView * testView = self.navigationController.navigationBar ;
CGRect frame = testView.layer.frame ;
testView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.0f) ;
testView.layer.frame = frame ;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    shake.duration = 1.0;

    shake.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 1.0 ,1.0)];
    shake.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.5, 1.0)];

    shake.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    shake.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [testView.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you first. I tried you code, but titleview have apparent jump, and it change flat also.

Comment: @Dracuuula I have edited my answer, but I am confused why you want this.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to emulate the behavior of Safari in iOS 7, in which the navigation bar grows and shrinks during scrolling.

Comment: @AaronBrager If so, I think he'd better use custom `UIView` instead of `UINavigationBar`

Comment: @KudoCC After i tried some methods, custom UIView instead of UINavigationBar is the best

Comment: @Dracuuula Yes, `UINavigationBar` did much work in private and modify on it is risky.